# Finding equilibrium solutions of $y'+y=te^{-1}+1$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y'+y=te^{-1}+1$$

I'm trying to find the equilibrium solutions, and the "long time behaviour" of this differential equation

I quickly recognized the form $y'+p(t)y=g(t)$ and found $\mu (t)$ to be $e^{t}$, since $p(t)=1$, $\mu (t)=e^{\int p(t)dt}$.

Then, since $\mu (t)y=\int\mu (t)g(t)dt$, I found $y=te^{t}$.

The solutions manual says that $\mu (t)=e^{2t}$, but I see no reason that the $2$ should be there.

Then long term behaviour would be the $\lim_{t->\infty} y=te^{t}$.  Any help plotting this in Matlab using 'dirfield.m' would be also much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: @LetThisNightExplode: Are you sure that $g(t)$ is supposed to be $te^{-1}$? If so, then your integratong factor is correct, but your solution is not.

Comment: I just did a correction to the original equation.  I think I need to move that $-1$ over, since it's not  a function of $t$ either.  So then my $p(t)$ is $y-1$.

Comment: No, you want to leave it where it is. If you moved it over, your $p(t)$ would be $1-\frac1y,$ which is not an explicit function of $t.$

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Note that by examining the form of the solution given by the manual, we have the indeterminate $c$ multiplied by $e^{-t},$ rather than $e^{-2t}.$ This suggests that the integrating factor $e^t$ was, in fact, intended by the manual, and that $e^{2t}$ was just a typo.

Assuming that the posted ODE is correct, then $$(ye^t)'=y'e^t+ye^t=(y'+y)e^t=te^{t-1}+e^t,$$ so $$ye^t=\int\left(te^{t-1}+e^t\right)\,dt=(t-1)e^{t-1}+e^t+c,$$ and so $$y=(t-1)e^{-1}+1+ce^{-t}$$ is the family of solutions to the posted ODE.

---

How could such a different solution have been obtained? Well, it turns out that, letting $u=t^2e^{-t}/2+1+ce^{-t}$ for any constant $c,$ we then have $$u'+u=te^{-t}+1.$$ Thus, I suspect that the ODE was intended to be $$y'+y=te^{-t}+1,$$ instead. From *this* ODE, we have in a similar fashion that $$(ye^t)'=t+e^t,$$ whence $$ye^t=\int(t+e^t)\,dt=t^2/2+e^t+c,$$ and we have exactly the solution family from the manual (as one would hope).